# No se puede leer propiedad al unir dos entidades en una

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net, mvc

Estoy colocando dos modelos en uno a través de un clase que los une, con el objetivo de asignarles valor qu obtengo de la BD pero me genera una excepción en la primer linea que lee el `read() -> Test.Models.Modelo.Pagos.get` devolvió null, no se por que no obtiene valor, las clases están en archivos separados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Controller**:

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    List<Modelo> obtener = GetPersonas();
    return View(obtener);
}

public List<Modelo> GetPersonas(){
    List<Modelo> lstPagos = new List<Modelo>();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=PC;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=yes;");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT p.Id_pago,c.Id_cliente,c.Nombre,p.Monto,c.Comision,p.Autorizacion,p.Comentario,p.Fecha FROM Pagos p inner join Cliente c on p.Id_cliente=c.Id_cliente where p.Autorizacion=0", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read()){
        Modelo persona = new Modelo();
        persona.Pagos.IdPago = Convert.ToInt16(dr["Id_pago"]);
        persona.Pagos.IdCliente = Convert.ToInt16(dr["Id_cliente"]);
        persona.Cliente.Nombre = dr["Nombre"].ToString();
        persona.Pagos.Monto = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Monto"]);
        persona.Cliente.Comision = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Comision"]);
        persona.Pagos.Autorizacion = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["Autorizacion"]);
        persona.Pagos.Fecha= Convert.ToDateTime( dr["Fecha"]);

        lstPagos.Add(persona);
    }

    con.Close();
    return lstPagos;
}
```

**class Cliente**:

```
public class Cliente{
    public int IdCliente { get;  set; }
    public string Nombre { get;  set; }
    public int Comision { get;  set; }
    public int Estatus { get;  set; }
}
```

**clase pagos**:

```
public class Pagos{
    public int IdPago { get; set; }
    public int IdCliente { get; set; }
    public Decimal Monto { get; set; }
    public bool Autorizacion { get; set; }
    public string Comentario { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string NombreCliente { get; set; }

}
```

**clase Modelo**:

```
public class Modelo{
    public Pagos Pagos { get; private set; }
    public Cliente Cliente { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te comento, para manipular las propiedades de un objeto dentro de otro, este se tiene que *construir (o instanciar)* primeramente.

```
Modelo persona = new Modelo();
//Creamos Pagos
persona.Pagos = new Pagos();
persona.Pagos.IdPago = Convert.ToInt16(dr["Id_pago"]);
persona.Pagos.IdCliente = Convert.ToInt16(dr["Id_cliente"]);
//Creamos Cliente
persona.Cliente = new Cliente();
persona.Cliente.Nombre = dr["Nombre"].ToString();
persona.Pagos.Monto = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Monto"]);
persona.Cliente.Comision = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Comision"]);
persona.Pagos.Autorizacion = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["Autorizacion"]);
persona.Pagos.Fecha= Convert.ToDateTime( dr["Fecha"]);

lstPagos.Add(persona);
```

Por defecto cuando creas `Modelo`, su propiedad *Pagos* se creara con valor `null`, si quieres alterar este comportamiento deberías modificar el constructor de `Modelo`:

```
public class Modelo{
    public Pagos Pagos { get; private set; }
    public Cliente Cliente { get; private set; }

    //Modifico el constructor
    public Modelo(){
        Pagos = new Pagos();
        Cliente = new Cliente();
    }
}

// y con esto ya podrias hacer lo que hiciste en primera instancia

Modelo persona = new Modelo();
persona.Pagos.IdPago = Convert.ToInt16(dr["Id_pago"]);
persona.Pagos.IdCliente = Convert.ToInt16(dr["Id_cliente"]);
persona.Cliente.Nombre = dr["Nombre"].ToString();
persona.Pagos.Monto = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Monto"]);
persona.Cliente.Comision = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Comision"]);
persona.Pagos.Autorizacion = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["Autorizacion"]);
persona.Pagos.Fecha= Convert.ToDateTime( dr["Fecha"]);

lstPagos.Add(persona);
```

Comment: si es correcto, no lo sabia  ya funciono

Comment: Alli se actualizo la respuesta, dándote mas opciones.